# Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/unpr?p0=

Tags: angularjs, cookies

Im getting this error when I try to include $cookie into my controller.

Anyone can explain to me what I did wrong?

I have angular-cookie.js in the index.html
I have called ngcookies module in config.js
In my controller, I have

```
    angular
    .module('homer')
    .controller('authCtrl', authCtrl)
function authCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $location, $cookies, $http, sweetAlert, Data) {
debugger;
```

If I remove $cookies from here, no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that You are not Injecting Dependency Correctly.

It should be injected in the following way :-

```
var MyModule= angular.module('myapp', ['ngCookies']);

MyModule.controller('MyController', function($scope, $cookies, $window, $cookieStore) {
  $cookies.cookieSimple = 'Simple Cookie ';

});
```

Refer:- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies, and https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies

I Found an Example For you http://plnkr.co/edit/bkhTxFsbHe6wMnapaDiY?p=preview

Sorry Dude it is in Some Different language ... But you can understand the Functionality.

Good Luck !!

Comment: You Got it  ? one quick question Are you Using Meanjs ?

Comment: and it turned out the problem might be the angular-cookie.js file I downloaded, I switched to another angular-cookie.js, it all works now...  after spent hours of debugging.....